# Why in landscape orientation in simulator all the subviews appear out of order?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios-simulator

I was doing a sample app in ipad. I added about 4 to 5 imageviews to  the left side of the view vertically. This view will appear when we select the corresponding entry in the splitviewcontroller. In ipad simulator too, all the images were loading and all are working fine in portrait orientation.

But when I rotate the simulator to landscape orientation, these imageviews doesnt appear where i placed them. Some of them overlapping each other, some have half of their part in the navigation bar and all. Has gone completely out of order. I am confused why is all this happening. Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have read your question very carefully. I understood the problem that you faced.

Here is the solution for you.

- Open your viewControllers.xib.
- Select your image views
- Press Command + 3 ( for size inspector )
- Go into 'View Size' section
- 'concentrate' on auto resizing option
- if there is no red lines below 'auto resizing', it will work as you want.

Hope, you understand what I want to say. If you found any difficulty in my answer, please add comment.

Comment: Hey, I did it and I undestood what u were trying to say. Thanks a lot man. Till now, I didnt knew it had such a funtionality too.

Comment: Hi i too have the same problem but i am doing my project as programmaticaly without using .xib, so how can i solve this issue.Please do reply...

Comment: @Cathy - first, Please Ask a new question. Place the code that you have tried - I will surely observe your code & will suggest to solve your issue.

Comment: Hi i have asked a new question and also placed the code on Autoresizing subviews programmatically. But no one replied. Please atleast you reply me.